# ReportViewer showing only Headers by adding datasource dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I'm creating report using Report Viewer(in Second Form) by clicking button in First Form. I'm sending SELECT query data from first form.
In second form_Loaded,i am displaying the report by reading data from database.

```
namespace TrainingReports
{
    public partial class AlarmReport : Form
    {
        private String Sessionstr;
        public AlarmReport(String strsess)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Sessionstr = strsess;
        }

        private void AlarmReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             this.reportViewer1.Reset();
             this.reportViewer1.Visible = true;
             this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;             
             this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TrainingReports.AlarmLog.rdlc";
             this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

             String sQuery = "SELECT * FROM alarmlogtbl WHERE (SessionID='" + Sessionstr + "')";
             MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter(sQuery, Properties.Settings.Default.DBPerfScoreConnectionString);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             ada.Fill(ds);

             ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();             
             reportDataSource.Name = "DBPerfScoreDataSet_alarmlogtbl";
             reportDataSource.Value = ds.Tables[0];

             this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);                      
             this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }
    }
}
```

From MainForm, im invoking Report form by the button action:

```
private void OnButtonAlarmActionClick(object sender, ListViewColumnMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewHitTestInfo info = SessionList.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            ListViewItem item = info.Item;
            String sSession = item.SubItems[1].Text;// Index; 
            AlarmReport alrmRpt = new AlarmReport(sSession);           
            alrmRpt.Show();           

        }
```

Report generated but only the headers are showing no table data.

I have attached Microsoft.ReportViewer in Second Form and have chosen 'DEsign a New Report' and added DataSource and AlamrmLogtbl and all comluns in it.Now in ReportViewer Tasks menu, Choose report shows TrainingReports.AlarmLog.rdlc". 
Data which are fetching from databse doesnot getting showed.

*solved: Problem in Select query.*

Comment: keep break point and check whether your query is getting the data or not.

Comment: It would be awesome if you write a little summary (as an answer) on how you've solved your problem, so you can select it as your solution.